# Can you stream from a HTTPS server using HLS?

Tags: xcode, swift, http, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm wondering wether or not it's possible to stream from a HTTPS server using HLS, using the following code -

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8")
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame

        player.play()
```

I can stream from an HTTP server, but when I changed the URL to the URL of my company's server it doesn't work, the only difference is that the video of my company has HTTPS in it's URL and apple's sample video doesn't, I'm testing on the Emulator in XCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can stream HLS from an HTTPS server. HLS streams are transfered over HTTP and HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS and most of the time it is transparent to the client. The only thing you need is support for HTTPS in the player which all major ones already have.

`https://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8` is not working because the `devimages.apple.com` certificate is invalid. Just browse the [url](https://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8) using your browser. It will warn you and give you additional information about what exactly is wrong.

I guess the problem with your company server is the same - wrong or self-signed certificate.

Another quick way to validate an https server is to user curl. For example:

```
curl "https://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
```

complains with:

```
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'devimages.apple.com'
```

Comment: The apple-link is working, my company's isn't, how would I go about adding in support for HTTPS, my company wants an inline video player, so I have to create an app with an inline player for Iphone

Comment: try running `curl <company-url>' and see what happens. If curl complains then your company server has a bad certificate.

Comment: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl I'm getting this error when I curl something

Comment: You should google how to install curl with https support on mac. If you are still having problems then you should ask a question here or in the appropriate stack exchange site. This question and comments is not the place for instructions how to install curl.

Comment: just checked and the SSL certificate isn't trusted, is this an issue?

Comment: Yes, it's an issue. There must be a chain of trust between the host and the browser. Otherwise there is no way for the browser to trust that the host is the one that it's claiming to be. The certificate is probably self-signed. I advice you to contact the server administrator and ask him about https an why the certificate is invalid.